# WSO API Manager endpoints and cloud

Tags: wso2, cloud, wso2-api-manager, endpoint, api-manager

I have several questions about WSO2 API Manager that I am not able to figure out reading the documentation:

1. Is it possible to setup a "default" basepath for all API? for example if I have to switch my endpoints from localhost:8080/rest/myapi to 12.43.56.89:8080/rest/myapi is it possible to do it without editing any single API's enpoint?
2. Is it possible to create create a role which allows access only to sandbox endpoint but not to production endpoint? The only way to do this, as far as I know, is to manually block the access to production once the user has subscribed the API. My idea is to allow all users to access the sandbox but enable only trusted users to access the production APIs once their applications have been validated.
3. Is it possible to distribute several instances of the AM Gateway? Accordingly with documentation it seems that is only possible to run gateway, store, and publisher+keymanager on different servers but not to run multiple instance of the gateway in parallel.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can use a variable for endpoint base path like this.

`http://{uri.var.host}:{uri.var.port}/apis/weather`

These variables can be taken from system variables. [See this](http://nuwanzone.blogspot.com/2015/03/api-gateways-with-dedicated-back-ends.html) for how to do it.

2) You can use [Key Generation (i.e. OAuth App Registration) Workflows](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+a+Key+Generation+Workflow) for this. This will send a approval request to admin user. If you want to automate it to approve based in user roles or something, you can [customize workflows](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Customizing+a+Workflow+Extension).

3) You can have [multiple gateways](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+the+Gateway).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So the only way to achieve point 2 is to install the WSO2 BPS, I cannot handle production/sandbox only using standard roles right?

Comment: You can write a custom workflow to check on user's roles and automatically approve. Don't need BPS in that case.